# ¿Cómo puedo selecionar el primer elemento css con nth-child?

Tags: html, css

Trabajando con html/css me he encontrado con este problema, quiero cambiar el color del primer enlace, lo quiero hacer con nth-child(1) pero seleciona todos. ¿Qué tengo que poner para selecionar el primer link (1er enlace) en css?

```
<div class="links">
        <ul class="lc-checks">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"><li><span class="lc-checks__feature ">1er enlace</span></li></a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"><li><span class="lc-checks__feature ">2do enlace</span></li></a>
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"><li><span class="lc-checks__feature ">3er enlace</span></li></a>
                    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La entrada y la lista no la has construido según la norma, los elementos

no van  dentro de los , sino al revés.

```
<div class="links">
    <ul class="lc-checks">  
        <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="lc-checks__feature ">1er enlace</span></li></a>
         <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="lc-checks__feature ">2do enlace</span></li></a>
         <li> <a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="lc-checks__feature ">3er enlace</span></li></a>
    </ul>
```

Luego el css que queires sería

```
.links ul li:nth-child(1) a{
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: El problema es que el html no es mío, estoy usando una tool, es la siguiente: https://ogads.com , y por eso no puedo cambiarlo. ¿Habría manera de hacerlo con el html que está en la pregunta inicial?

Comment: .links ul a:nth-child(1) li usando esto he podido conseguirlo, edita tu respuesta y la doy por válida para ayudar a más usuarios. Gracias!

Comment: Si, efectivamente a:nth-child() funciona, pero el HTML que usas es sintácticamente incorrecto (aunque funcione, al menos en chrome) , por eso lo corregí en la respuesta. Si no puedes cambiarlo pues tendrás que usar la solución del a:nth-child() .